# How can I make a container take all the screen width?

Tags: android, flutter, containers, screen

How can I make this container (with the black color) take all the screen's width

[image]

Here is my code for the moment:

```dart
Container(
              height: 50,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: const Color(0xFF262724),
              child: const Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.mic_none, color: Colors.white),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.check_box_outlined,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

I tried to set the width to be `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` which apparently is the width of the screen, but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use double.infinity in with but I think You use padding or margin in parent widget

Comment: yep I'm using padding on the parent widget (top: 50, left: 20, right: 20), that's why the container is not taking all the width available, is there a way to override the parent's width ?